# How do you optimize searching a large file in Python

Tags: python, file, search, optimization

I have a large file containing around 8 million lines of file names, and I am trying to search for file names that include a certain value. Finding one is fine, but the issue is that I am trying to search for around 50k unique values, and the time it takes to search is immense.

```
with open('UniqueValueList.txt') as g:
    uniqueValues = g.read().splitlines()

outF = open("Filenames_With_Unique_Values.txt", "w")
with open('Filenames_File.txt') as f:
    fileLine = f.readlines()
    for line in fileLine:
        for value in uniqueValues:
            if value in line:
                outF.write(line)
outF.close()
```

I am unable to load the filenames file into memory for it is much too large. Is there any other way to optimize this search?

Comment: Don't try to read the entire file (that's what you do with `fileLine = f.readlines()`). Just iterate on the lines of the file: `for line in f:`. If it is still too slow, you'll probably have to improve the way you look for your 50k different values in each line.

Comment: Are you on a forking system like linux and mac or a spawning system like windows? If forking, once fileLines is built you could run a multiprocessing pool and divy up values to search among them. Maybe even write a temporary file per process and then concatenate them at the end. I don't know it if would be faster, but with 50k values, it could be.

Comment: Most of all, use your OS text search capabilities, **not** an interpretive language.

Comment: First thing would be to jump out of the inner for loop after you found a match.

Comment: @Wups - that can work great but depends on OP's intent. If a value can match multiple file names, then all of the lines will need to be searched.

Comment: @tdelaney Yes, I need to search each file name listing to see if it contains any of the unique values. I have been able to optimize it slightly by reading directly from f instead of fileLines, but it is not nearly enough. I am looking at using grep to filter out the files from the large file, to see if that helps at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My two theories are to (1) memory map the file and use a multiline regular expression for each value search, and (2) farm the work out to multiple subprocesses. I combined the two and came up with the following. It may be possible to do the mmap in the parent and share, but I went the easy route and just did it in each subprocess assuming the operating system will figure out efficient sharing for you.

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import os
import mmap
import re

def _value_find_worker_init(filename):
    """Called when initializing mp.Pool to open an mmaped file in subprocesses.
    The file is `global mmap_file` so that the worker can find it.
    """
    global mmap_file
    filenames_fd = os.open(filename, os.O_RDONLY)
    mmap_file = mmap.mmap(filenames_fd, length=os.stat(filename).st_size,
        access=mmap.ACCESS_READ)

def _value_find_worker(value):
    """Return a list of matching lines in `global mmap_file`"""
    # multiline regex for findall
    regex = b"(?m)^.*?" + value + b".*?$"
    matched = re.compile(regex).findall(mmap_file)
    print(regex, matched)
    return matched

def find_unique():
    with open("UniqueValueList.txt", "rb") as g:
        uniqueValues = [line.strip() for line in g]
    with open('UniqueValueList.txt', "rb") as g:
        uniqueValues = [line.strip() for line in g]
    with mp.Pool(initializer=_value_find_worker_init,
            initargs=("Filenames_File.txt",)) as pool:
        matched_values = set()
        for matches in pool.imap_unordered(_value_find_worker, uniqueValues):
            matched_values.update(matches)
    with open("Filenames_With_Unique_Values.txt", "wb") as outfile:
        outfile.writelines(value + b"\n" for value in matched_values)

find_unique()
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use the file object as an iterator. The iterator will return each line one by one, which can be processed. This will not read the whole file into memory and it’s suitable to read large files in Python.

Help your self with this clear tutorial
[How to read huge file with Python](https://www.journaldev.com/32059/read-large-text-files-in-python)